# PostgreSQL EXISTS and null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists

For example use `Test` table with only positive `id` value.
Query `select 1 from public.Test where id = 0` return empty result.

But when I use this query:

```
select case 
           when exists(select 1 from public.Test where id = 0) then 'exist' 
           else 'not exist' 
       end
```

result is - `not exist`

For query:

```
select case when exists(select null) then 'exist' else 'not exist' end
```

result is - 'exist'

And for query:

```
do $$
declare _query int = 7;
begin
_query:= (select 1 from public.Test where id = 0);
RAISE NOTICE '%', _query;
end;
$$;
```

result is - `NULL`

So what's the difference between query returning empty result and `null`? And why does the `_query` variable for the empty query result have a `null` value?

Comment: in psql session,  first run `select from test where id = 0;` then run `\gdesc` it will says `The command has no result, or the result has no columns.` so there is no datatype, no value, so it will assign null to _query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT FROM public.test WHERE id = 0) AS any_matching_rows
```

No extra `CASE` wrapper. `EXISTS` returns `true` / `false` (never `null`). All done.
The `SELECT` list of the nested query can stay empty as it's irrelevant to `EXISTS`.

> And why does the `_query` variable for the empty query result have a `null` value?

That's because "no row" is converted to a `null` value in an  assignment to a scalar variable. (Feeding that query to `EXISTS` converts "no row" to `false` instead - and the existence of any rows to `true`.)

Answer (score 2):

`exists` only tests the **presence** of a row, not the value(s) returned by the query.

In fact, the expression in the select list isn't not even evaluated for an EXISTS operator.

You could even write `select exists (select 1/0)` without getting an error (this would return true). Although `select 1/0` as a standalone query would result in an error.